# Play Store: Should I add localizations for the same language in different regions?

Tags: android, localization, google-play, translation

I want to publish my app in the Google Play Store. Does it make sense to add localizations for different regions with the same language? For my store listing and/or inside of my apk?

E.g.: I'm already using en-US. Should I add en-GB even though the content would be exactly the same?

Does anybody know whether this could for instance result in an increased distribution in Great Britain?

Comment: why don't you use just `en` without any US, GB, if the content is the same?

Comment: Your idea seems to be a good solution to provide different resources inside of the apk. However, this option isn't available for the store listing in the first place. Furthermore, I think it does not work for English(!) apk resources either, because the default resource folder (not containing any language or country codes) represents en_US, doesn't it?

Comment: it actually doesn't. It represents the default language whatever it is. So it works like this: check region specific + language specific (`values-en_US`). If not found - check language specific (`values-en`), if not found - fall back to the default (`values`).

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. So my question is answered for the apk part, thank you! However, I'm still not sure how to handle the store listing. Would be interesting to know, what different regions do affect.